# Convert an array to an unsigned integer

Tags: c, arrays, int, unsigned

Hello I have a two dimensional `array[8][8]`, the elements are filled with either `1` or `0`. So my question is: How do I convert one whole row into an unsigned integer that is 8 bits long?

I'm coding in C.

Comment: Did you try? Show your code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
int array[8][8]; /* this is what you have */

unsigned row0 = 0;
int i;
for( i = 0; i < 8; i++ ) row0 |= (unsigned)array[0][i] << i;

/* row0 now contains the converted number */
```

This assumes your data is least-significant-bit first.

Comment: OP wants the integer to be 1 byte long. `unsigned` is typically going to be four bytes long.

Comment: yeah its ok i just wanted the general idea of the conversion. im actually using unsigned long long